# Rails using ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore to save variable between two api calls (controller methods)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached

I have APIs where I want to save some values that would be accessible between each API method, so I am trying to use the ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore. I'm probably not using MemoryStore correctly (never used it, cannot find a specific tutorial for it)

Am I using MemoryStore correctly? Seems like it should be super simple, but can't seem to save any value.

```
class MyController
  # 1st API handler /post
  def first
    @cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new() if @cache.nil?
    @cache.write('shared_val', params['user_key'])
  end

  # 2nd API handler /post
  def second
    @cache = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new() if @cache.nil?
    saved_val = @cache.read('shared_val')
    puts "#{saved_val}"  # nil?????
  end
```

I also tried some examples I saw in SO answers, but still cannot seem to save the value.

```
  # In config file
  config.cache_store = :memory_store

  # 1st API handler /post
  def first
    Rails.cache.write("ABC", "abc")
    check_val = Rails.cache.read('ABC')
    puts "VALUE: #{check_val}"  # shows correct 'abc'
  end

  # 2nd API handler /post
  def second
    Rails.cache.fetch("ABC")  # gets nil, why???
    Rails.cache.read("ABC)    # also nil
  end
```

Comment: What web server are you using? The memory store only shares data within a single process. Per the docs, if you're using Puma in clustered mode, or Phusion Passenger, or any other multi-process or multi-server web server, then your second request may not have access to the same cache. Also, `fetch` is a cache method meant to read OR write. It reads using the key you pass as an arg, and takes a block to write back to the cache if the read fails. It's for lazy caching. You may need to use a redis or memcached store instead. Your second example looks much more like what I would expect to work.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/94b5cd3a20edadd6f6b8cf0bdf1a4d4919df86cb/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/memory_store.rb#L7 That's where I read that in the docs, by the way.

Comment: Nate, I'm just running it in dev environment using puma. The puma web_concurrency settings are commented and I also tried setting max threads to just 1. Still just get nil when 2nd API is called.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#basic-caching what if you set `config.action_controller.perform_caching = true`?

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!, sorry I was too lazy to check the entire development.rb file and the else block was disabling my settings. Thanks!!! Can you post your answer and I'll accept it. I'm quite sure it might help somebody down the road since I've googled for answers many times.

Comment: No problem! I just made it an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`config.action_controller.perform_caching` is false by default. You need to turn it on in other environments.